# Injecting Ninject dependencies into WebApiConfig in Web API 2

Tags: ninject, asp.net-web-api2

is it possible to inject dependencies into the WebApiConfig class using Ninject?

This is my WebApiConfig class.

```
        public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

                config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new ErrorHandlerMessageHandler(*NEEDS DEPENDENCY*));
            }
        }
```

And this is my  NinjectHttpApplication declaration

```
 public class WebApiApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            //bindings
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I didn't have to do this but I have created a blog post on how to do this [here](http://markwalsh.site/development/2014/11/25/Ninject-Asp.Net-WebApi-2-Integration)

Comment: thanks this post helped me, but I think some folks will already have this NinjectWebCommon class if they're adding WebAPI to an existing MVC project. I found that the following line was all I needed to add: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(_kernel);` after the `RegisterServices(_kernel)` call in the `CreateKernel` method. Note that this is the `NinjectDependencyResolver` from the `Ninject.Web.WebApi` namespace (may have to download separate NuGet package). Thanks!

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to do this. My NinjectWebCommon class already contains that line, however even I have one property decorated with the [Inject] attribute, the dependency is not being injected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you moved your blog? Seems it's not available anymore.

Comment: Updated my blog link for you @GonzaloMéndez